# Sending two AJAX request from one document

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been developing my website for over a year now, and I am learning along the way. I am now working on an upload page that uses AJAX to process the upload and show a progress bar while it is doing it, after the file is uploaded it stores all the uploaded files temporarily in a session array then when the final button is pressed the image path will be stored in the database.

However, I have stumbled across an issue with AJAX - which I am not really good at - that I can't overcome. When the images are uploaded it shows a preview of these images with a small delete button over each image for users to delete the image they don't want anymore.

What I came to realization is that once I upload an image with AJAX the 'delete image' function won't process as the AJAX request has already been processed. Should I include the functions in separate '.js' files or am I just handling it wrong.
[an image to explain all of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCarO.png)

The AJAX code:

```
//file upload ajax


$(function() {
  /* variables */

  var bar = $('.bar');
  var progress = $('.progress');

  /* submit form with ajax request using jQuery.form plugin */
  $('.upload_form').ajaxForm({

    /* set data type json */
  //  dataType:'json',

    /* reset before submitting */
    beforeSend: function() {
      bar.width('0%');
      progress.css('display', 'block');
    },

    /* progress bar call back*/
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      var pVel = percentComplete + '%';
      bar.width(pVel);
    },

    /* complete call back */
    complete: function(output){
    //  var responseMessage = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
    progress.css('display', 'none');
    document.getElementById('next_step').innerHTML = ''.innerHTML = '<form method="post"><input type="submit" class="final_upload red_submit" name="uploadSubmit" value="الانتهاء" /></form>';
    //$('.status-message').html('<p>'+output.responseText+'</p>');
    var response = output.responseText;
    var response_cut = response.substring(response.indexOf('<p class="n-st'), response.indexOf('cut text!'));
    var response_preview = response.substring(response.indexOf('<div class="n-im'), response.indexOf('cut me!'));
      $('.status-message').empty().html(response_cut);
      $('#preview_images').empty().html(response_preview);
      }

  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#upload_btn').change(function(){
    $('#upload_files').trigger('click');
  });
});

//delete image on click

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.preview-img').click(function(){
          var current_image = $(this);
          var img_src = $(this).attr('data-img-src');
          var img_count = parseInt($('.images_count').val());
          var url = 'upload.php';
          $.post(url, {del_img : img_src}, function(count_img){
              console.log(count_img);
              current_image.hide();
              var new_count = img_count + 1;
              $('.images_count').val(new_count);
              $('.status-message').empty().html('تم مسح الصورة بنجاح، تبقى لديك '+new_count+' صورة');
          });
    });
  });
```

Sorry for the language it is Arabic, but it doesn't mean anything important..

Comment: post your ajax code.it may helps us to give perfect code

Comment: Hey, sure I will update the post now!

Comment: Don't store their details in session. Add a hidden input to your page for each file with the file path returned by the Ajax upload. Then if someone deletes an image you can remove the input for that file.

Answer (score 0):

**You can send multiple HTTP requests from the same document**, you are not limited to one at a time.

Note however, that it is not guaranteed in which order they complete. Also note that browsers [limit the number of open HTTP requests per origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser), so you may be seeing some delays if you are going overboard with the number of connections.

Comment: Hello @Timo, sorry but I am not understanding it at all. I have updated and added my AJAX code if you could please look at it and tell me where I am wrong?